# jquery changing class on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

This simple code should change the class of the body element. But it doesn't work!

May the problem be in the wrong jQuery version link?

Besides, pretty strange, but in http://jsfiddle.net/4Bfa7/1/ it seems to work!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $("li.work").click(function(){
        $('body').removeClass();
        $('body').addClass("work");
});

$("li.pret").click(function(){
        $('body').removeClass();
        $('body').addClass("pret");
});

$("li.port").click(function(){
        $('body').removeClass();
        $('body').addClass("port");
});

$("li.contact").click(function(){
        $('body').removeClass();
        $('body').addClass("contact");
});
</script>    
<style>
body.contact{
background-color: red;}
</style>
</head>    
<body class="front">
<div id=" container">
<header>

<h1 id="site-name"><a href="/"> Crearea web site</a></h1>
<nav>

<ul class="main-nav">

<li class="careers"><a href="/ro" onclick><span class="menu-item-title"> HOME</span></a>
</li>
    <li class="work"><a href="/ro/about"><span class="menu-item-title"> About</span></a>
</li>
<li class="pret"><a href="/ro/preti"><span class="menu-item-title"> Pretul</span></a>
</li>

<li class="port"><a href="/ro/portfolio"><span class="menu-item-title"> Portofoliu</span></a>
</li>
<li class="contact"><a href="#"><span class="menu-item-title"> Contacte</span></a>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems you are missing document [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler.

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
  /* your event handlers */
});
```

The scripts in your code get executed before the DOM elements exist, so there isn't anything to bind on. `$( document ).ready()` gets executed when the DOM is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code inside document.ready.

```
$(function(){
   //
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap code into `$( document ).ready();` or place code at bottom of document directly before tag `</body>` or put the code in a separate file. This file will be load after loading document.

Answer (score 0):

Try `removeAttr` when document is loaded.
`RemoveAttr` method additional remove attribute from Your code, `removeClass` only clean `class` attribute value.

```
$(document).ready(function (){  

    $("li.work").click(function(){
            $('body').removeAttr('class');
            $('body').addClass("work");
    });

    $("li.pret").click(function(){
            $('body').removeAttr('class');
            $('body').addClass("pret");
    });

    $("li.port").click(function(){
            $('body').removeAttr('class');
            $('body').addClass("port");
    });

    $("li.contact").click(function(){
            $('body').removeAttr('class');
            $('body').addClass("contact");
    });
});
```